# Why my SVG is responsive but occasionally?

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, viewport, jsfiddle

I've created a 1000×1000 `svg` , but when I am running it in `Chrome browser` , if viewport size is less than 1000 the `svg image` is cropped automatically, having said that, I am not witnessing this problem in `jsFiddle` ! I am curious if it has anything to do with viewport dimension?
Take a look at what I'm trying:

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M100 100 h800 v800 h-800 v-800" fill="black" stroke="red" stroke-width="8" style="  stroke-dasharray: 4000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 4000;
  animation: dash 2s linear forwards infinite;" /><style>@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}</style>
  <text x="120" y="200" fill="skyblue" style="font-size:30;">
1: We do not endorse 'Aarogya Setu App'.
<tspan x="120" y="300">
2: To use this App you have to share
</tspan>
<tspan x="120" y="400">
your Name, Age, Sex, Location, Job and 
</tspan>
<tspan x="120" y="500">
other details with govt authorities.
 </tspan>
 <tspan x="120" y="600">
3: Also these details are transferred to
 </tspan>
 <tspan x="120" y="700">
nearby devices, via bluetooth using an
 </tspan>
 <tspan x="120" y="800">
encryption model, use only if you trust
 </tspan>
 <tspan x="120" y="870">
  your govt.
  </tspan>
</text>
</svg>
```

Here is `jsFiddle` link: https://jsfiddle.net/3fuh7ntj/
To see above `svg` in your browser, click here: https://covidnmap.000webhostapp.com/graphics.svg

Comment: Typo: It's viewBox not viewbox. Apparently when you put the svg inside a html document this get corrected

Comment: Change it to viewBox and see for yourself

Comment: I'm using `XML` format to view `SVG` in my browser. Should it still be `viewBox` instead of `viewbox` ? I don't think so! Even if it is a typo, it has to do nothing with browser's viewport I guess!

Comment: Dear [enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta) you are right, it is happening because of this `typo` which was auto corrected in `jsFiddle` , I've edited my `script` and changed `viewbox` into `viewBox` and now browser is handling it in `responsive way` resulting into change in its dimension with the change in the dimension of viewport! **Thanks a lot for your help, I was stuck here for a while, thanks for your help!**